# Is it counted as shirk joining a discord server with the word "god" on its name?

Tags: halal-haram, fiqh, shirk

Assalamualaikum,

So I joined a discord server from my friends but the server name is "*the person name* is god" now it's not a cult like discord server, it's just general server to meet and talk without any religious thing involved. They just use the name ironically. My question is if I joined that server will it count as me doing shirk? Is it haram to join that server?

Wassalamualaikum.

Answer (score 0):

Wassalamualaikum

Simple answer : **No**

**Why**,
Because shirk : In Islam, shirk is the sin of idolatry or polytheism. Islam teaches that God does not share His divine attributes with any partner. Associating partners with God is disallowed according to the Islamic doctrine of Tawhid. Mean to associate partner's with Allah(God).

*You have to believe that Allah has a mother/father/son/wife/husband/sister, to commit shirk. Or you have to worship some one else(not Allah) to commit shirk*.

And you didn't do that according to your questions.

> So I joined a discord server from my friends but the server name is "the person name is god" now it's not a cult like discord server, it's just general server to meet and talk without any religious thing involved. They just use the name ironically. My question is if I joined that server will it count as me doing shirk? Is it haram to join that server?

So it is not shirk.

Comment: Assalamualaikum, thank you for the answer brother! I hope you're staying safe and may Allah bless you in this world and hereafter!

Comment: @HelloIamMe your welcome. Wassalamualaikum